# Consent Variables - Can set but cannot read...

Tags: cookies, ee5

I am trying to get GDPR type consent to work on an EE5.1 site.

The methods are pretty much the same as the examples in the EE5 documentation.

Consent cookie is being set OK (I can see it appear in Chrome Inspector when a `consent_grant_url` button is pressed), but try as I might, I cannot get `{consent:ee:cookies_performance}` to pick up that a cookies has been set.

The setting code is

```
{exp:consent:form
    consent='ee:cookies_performance'
    form_id='cookieConsentForm'
    return='{current_uri}'
}
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" href="{consent_grant_url}">Accept</button>          
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info" href="{consent_withdraw_url}">Decline</button>
{/exp:consent:form}
```

the reading code is

```
{if consent:ee:cookies_performance}
    Google Tracking Code snippet
{/if}
```

but this refuses to fire.

Quoting out the `{consent:ee:cookies_performance}` tag reveals it to be empty (which explains why conditional won't fire) - but I cannot work out why.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious... any ideas / suggestions would be hugely helpful..  Thanks!  (EE5.1.0)

Answer (score 0):

Solution turns out to be in the setting: some confusion in documentation about how to construct the setting code.  But what worked was swapping to use the `exp:consent:requests` tag, and turning the form buttons into regular anchors.  Why it worked ( and / or worked sort-of before) is a mystery - but posting here in case useful to others:

```
{if ! consent:has_responded:ee:cookies_performance}
<div class="container-fluid cookie-consent" id="cookieConsent">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        {exp:consent:requests
            consent='ee:cookies_performance'
            }
            <h4>{consent_title}</h4>
            <p>{consent_request}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 align-self-center text-center">
            <a class="btn btn-block btn-success" href="{consent_grant_url}">Accept</a>          
            <a class="btn btn-block btn-outline-info" href="{consent_withdraw_url}">Decline</a>
        </div>
        {/exp:consent:requests}
    </div>
</div>
{/if}
```